# adding custom animation in canvas html5

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

this might be somewhat difficult but i wil still ask, so i made a starfield ,now what i want to do is to have my stars( a pair each) connected to eachother by a line ,now this line will expand as the stars move forward and disappear when the stars move out of the canvas .any help would be appreciated here this is difficult i have the logic but i seem unable to follow the correct way to implement it

```js
        function randomRange(minVal, maxVal) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxVal - minVal - 1)) + minVal;
        }

        function initStars() {
            for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
                stars[i] = {
                    x: randomRange(-25, 25),
                    y: randomRange(-25, 25),
                    z: randomRange(1, MAX_DEPTH)
                }
            }
        }

        function degToRad(deg) {
            radians = (deg * Math.PI / 180) - Math.PI / 2;
            return radians;

        }

        function animate() {
            var halfWidth = canvas.width / 2;
            var halfHeight = canvas.height / 2;

            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
                stars[i].z -= 0.2;

                if (stars[i].z <= 0) {
                    stars[i].x = randomRange(-25, 25);
                    stars[i].y = randomRange(-25, 25);
                    stars[i].z = MAX_DEPTH;
                }

                var k = 128.0 / stars[i].z;
                var px = stars[i].x * k + halfWidth;
                var py = stars[i].y * k + halfHeight;

                if (px >= 0 && px <= 1500 && py >= 0 && py <= 1500) {
                    var size = (1 - stars[i].z / 32.0) * 5;
                    var shade = parseInt((1 - stars[i].z / 32.0) * 750);
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + shade + "," + shade + "," + shade + ")";
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(px, py, size, degToRad(0), degToRad(360));
                    ctx.fill();
                }
            }
        }

        function animate() {
            var halfWidth = canvas.width / 2;
            var halfHeight = canvas.height / 2;

            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
                stars[i].z -= 0.2;

                if (stars[i].z <= 0) {
                    stars[i].x = randomRange(-25, 25);
                    stars[i].y = randomRange(-25, 25);
                    stars[i].z = MAX_DEPTH;
                }

                var k = 128.0 / stars[i].z;
                var px = stars[i].x * k + halfWidth;
                var py = stars[i].y * k + halfHeight;

                if (px >= 0 && px <= 1500 && py >= 0 && py <= 1500) {
                    var size = (1 - stars[i].z / 32.0) * 5;
                    var shade = parseInt((1 - stars[i].z / 32.0) * 750);
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + shade + "," + shade + "," + shade + ")";
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(px, py, size, degToRad(0), degToRad(360));
                    ctx.fill();
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
<head>
  <title>stars</title>
 
    <script    src="convergis.js"></script>
    <script>
    MAX_DEPTH = 32;
 
    var canvas, ctx;
    var stars = new Array(500);
 
    window.onload = function() {
      canvas = document.getElementById("tutorial");
      if( canvas && canvas.getContext ) {
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        initStars();
        setInterval(animate,17);
       }
    }
 
  
  </script>
    </head>
<body>
  <canvas id='tutorial' width='1500' height='1500'>
  
  </canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just say you want a lightspeed effect!

One way very cheap way to do it is to paint the background with some transparency. You can also render a set of points close together in order to make the illusion of the effect.

The good way to do it is shaders since they will allow you to add glow and some other nice image trickery that will make it look better. Here is a good example: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Xdl3D2

Below I used the canvas api `lineTo` and even with a fixed line width, it's a pretty good final result.

```js
var MAX_DEPTH = 64;
var LINELENGTH = 0.1;
var stars = new Array(500);
var canvas = document.getElementById("tutorial");
canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
initStars();
setInterval(animate,17);


function randomRange(minVal, maxVal) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxVal - minVal - 1)) + minVal;
}

function initStars() {
  for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
stars[i] = {
  x: randomRange(-25, 25),
  y: randomRange(-25, 25),
  z: randomRange(1, MAX_DEPTH)
}
  }
}

function degToRad(deg) {
  radians = (deg * Math.PI / 180) - Math.PI / 2;
  return radians;

}

function animate() {
  var halfWidth = canvas.width / 2;
  var halfHeight = canvas.height / 2;

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
stars[i].z -= 0.5;

if (stars[i].z <= 0) {
  stars[i].x = randomRange(-25, 25);
  stars[i].y = randomRange(-25, 25);
  stars[i].z = MAX_DEPTH;
}

var k = 254.0 / stars[i].z;
var px = stars[i].x * k + halfWidth;
var py = stars[i].y * k + halfHeight;

if (px >= 0 && px <= 1500 && py >= 0 && py <= 1500) {
  var size = (1 - stars[i].z / 32.0) * 2;
  var shade = parseInt((1 - stars[i].z / 32.0) * 750);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(" + shade + "," + shade + "," + shade + ")";
  ctx.lineWidth = size;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(px,py);
  var ox = size * (px - halfWidth) * LINELENGTH;
  var oy = size * (py - halfHeight) * LINELENGTH;
  ctx.lineTo(px + ox, py + oy);
  ctx.stroke();
}
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id='tutorial' width='1500' height='1500'></canvas>
```

Comment: No not a light effect .

Comment: When the circles appear a pair of them should be attached to each other by a line and when they move apart as the proceed the line should expand and disappear when the move too far apart and move out of the canvas

Comment: I updated the code to use lines instead of the cheaper method.

Comment: i think you dont get what i am saying , i mean that two opposite circle should be attached to each other by a line that expands as the move far apart  and then disappears

Comment: For that you will need a way to render the expanding line. The canvas API does not support that, so you will have to calculate a 3D projection or find a way to simulate it.

Comment: Ok thanks , but is it possible just to add it to  a single pair in canvas ? Can you explain please

Comment: I updated the answer, plz check the new code. I'll try to make a better one and you can track it here https://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/YJKMzb